# check if the parent has a specific class on it

Tags: sass

This is the usual list where one of the items is .open

for this I want to check if the parent (in this case is .item but its not relevant i think) has a specific class.
I've tried > but it doesnt seem to work.

Essentially how to put this:

```css
&.open .info {
    display: none;
}

&.open .inner-info {
    display: flex;
}
```

inside of the their specific classes:

```css
.info {
    display: flex;
    /* some other stuff */
}

.inner-info {
    display: none;
    /* some other stuff */
}
```

all of this is inside an `.item{}` block

So how do i have it so that i only have two blocks inside the `.item{}`?

Comment: use `:has` [learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) although not all major/modern browsers support it but in the near future they will.

Comment: I don't understand how that helps exactly

Comment: I think you need to be a little clearer in your question, I don't quite get what you're actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It seems overkill to me, but you can use a hacky way to do that using a mixin and various functions. Please note that this will work for your specific example but probably not for something else.

I used the helper functions [`str-to-list`](https://gist.github.com/benib/92b22ef0716d571d796a#file-str-to-list-scss) and [`nth-delete`](https://gist.github.com/Jakobud/ec056b52f3673cc369dc97f2c2428424?permalink_comment_id=2718495#gistcomment-2718495), which are not native to SASS.

```
@mixin parentWithClass($class) {
  $parent: nth-delete(str-to-list(#{&}), -1);
    
  @at-root #{selector.replace(&, $parent, #{$parent}#{$class})} {
    @content;
  }
}

.item {
  .inner {
    color: blue;
        
    @include parentWithClass(".open") {
      color: orange;
    }
  }
    
  .inner-info {
    color: red;
        
    @include parentWithClass(".open") {
      color: grey;
    }
  }
}
```

You can also nest `-info` in `inner`.